# Android : GridView Zoom

Tags: android, gridview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have two gridviews, they contains my custom views as their children. I have implemented a drag and drop functionality to drag a view from one grid to another. What I want to achieve now is when I drop my view on the main GameBoard grid, I want the Grid to Zoom automatically. I also want to implement Pinch zoom so that user can zoom in/out the grid by himself also. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried to increase the gridview column height and width dynamically, but it is not working out, please suggest me a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dig out a lot after solving this, but I end up in a black hole.  Revised entire game to remove the GridView and use basic Canvas to achieve all the functionality. Hope this helps someone.

Thanks